# Web-greeter Issue

Tags: lightdm

I am having issues getting the web-greeter to work for lightdm. I just get a black screen at boot and when I run the web greeter test I get the following output:

```
2021-03-01 12:25:09 [ DEBUG ] objects - objects.py:124 : _setup_logger | Logger is ready.
2021-03-01 12:25:09 [ DEBUG ] app - app.py:57 : _wh_load_config | Try load config using key: WebGreeter
2021-03-01 12:25:09 [ DEBUG ] window - window.py:78 : _initialize | Initializing
Main Window Received signal 11 SEGV_MAPERR 000000000000
#0 0x7f85d5fe89a5 <unknown>
#1 0x7f85d4d28501 <unknown>
#2 0x7f85d5fe8d3d <unknown>
#3 0x7f85e3062bb0 <unknown> r8: 0000000000000001  r9: 00000000024a62a0 
     r10: 0000000000000002 r11: 00007f85dfedc000  r12: 00000000026849e0
     r13: 0000000002493550 r14: 0000000000000000  r15: 00007f85dffcd280
      di: 0000000000001f01  si: 00007f85dffcf210   bp: 00000000024aff40
      bx: 0000000000000001  dx: 00000000024410b0   ax: 00000000024410b0
      cx: 0000000000000000  sp: 00007ffd9dd09728   ip: 0000000000000000
     efl: 0000000000010206 cgf: 002b000000000033  erf: 0000000000000014
     trp: 000000000000000e msk: 0000000000000000  cr2: 0000000000000000
[end of stack trace] Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
```

Anyone have any idea what the error is above or what can be causing it? I reinstalled with all the dependencies but still get the same output.